# Multiple screens positioning in React-Native

Tags: ios, iphone, layout, react-native

I'm approaching to react-native (yeah, it's awesome) from a few weeks. Reading this great post on Medium 
https://medium.com/@elieslama/responsive-design-in-react-native-876ea9cd72a8#.qmwrb3ruq
 I think I've understand how to resize components like views and text properties (font size). But, and here is the problem, how can I set view properties like *marginTop* to be scaled to various screen sizes?
For example:

`{
...
   firstView:{
     marginTop : 10
   }
...
}`

*marginTop* is not the same on iPhone 5 and iPhone 6.
Can anyone provide a simple example on how to do this?
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default all units in react native use density independent pixels. You can use [PixelRatio](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pixelratio.html#get) to get the device pixel density. 
For margins you probably dont want to scale it with different pixel density. So , you can use it as

```
{
...
   firstView:{
     marginTop : PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(10)
   }
...
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a try! Thank you!

Comment: Should be *marginTop : PixelRatio.getPixelSizeForLayoutSize(5)* a good option too?

Comment: Yes. You are right. That would be a better option. I will update the answer. Thanks.